# 2 tables horizontally

Tags: tables, tabulary, hhline

how can I have both well organized arrays with the same number of lines and organize the underlining in each part of the array ??

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash }m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }b{#1}}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{C{8.5cm}C{8.5cm}}
\begin{tabular}[t]{C{1.5cm}L{7cm}}
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}}{\cellcolor{Gray}A} &\multicolumn{1}{m{7cm}}{} \\ 
AIX & Advanced Interactive eXecutive\\
AMP & Access Module Processor\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}}{\cellcolor{Gray}B} &\multicolumn{1}{m{7cm}}{} \\ 
BDDF & Banque De Détail en France\\\
BI & Business Intelligence\\
BNPP & Banque Nationale de Paris Paribas\\
BO & Business Objects \\
BPF & Banque Privée France\\
BTEQ & Batch \textbf{TE}radata Query\\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}}{\cellcolor{Gray}C} &\multicolumn{1}{m{7cm}}{} \\ 
CBP & Centre de Banque Privée\\
CEO & Chief Executive Officer\\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}}{\cellcolor{Gray}D} &\multicolumn{1}{m{7cm}}{} \\ 
DR & Direction Régionale\\
DTU & Dossier de Test Unitaires\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}}{\cellcolor{Gray}E} &\multicolumn{1}{m{7cm}}{} \\ 
ENSA & Ecole Nationale des Sciences Appliquées\\
ETL & Extract Transform Load \\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}}{\cellcolor{Gray}F} &\multicolumn{1}{m{7cm}}{} \\ 
FDC & Fond De Commerce externe\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}}{\cellcolor{Gray}G} &\multicolumn{1}{m{7cm}}{} \\ 
GL & Génie Logiciel\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}}{\cellcolor{Gray}I} &\multicolumn{1}{m{7cm}}{} \\
IAC & Info centre Animation Commercial\\
IBM & International Business Machines\\
IBM AT & IBM Applications \& Technologies\\ 
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular}[t]{C{1.5cm}L{7cm}}
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}}{} &\multicolumn{1}{m{6cm}}{}\\
IHM & Interface Hommes Machines\\
IPS & IT Production Services\\
IT &  Information Technology\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}}{\cellcolor{Gray}K} &\multicolumn{1}{m{7cm}}{} \\ 
KM & Knowledge Management\\
KSH & Korn shell\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}}{\cellcolor{Gray}M} &\multicolumn{1}{m{6cm}}{} \\ 
MEP & la Mise En Pr oduction\\
MEQ & la Mise En Qualification\\
MOA & Maitrise d’OuvrAge\\
MOE  & Maitrise d’Oeuvre \\
MPP & Massively Parallel Processing\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}}{\cellcolor{Gray}O} &\multicolumn{1}{m{6cm}}{} \\ 
ODBC & Open DataBase Connectivity\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}}{\cellcolor{Gray}P} &\multicolumn{1}{m{6cm}}{} \\ PE & Parsing Engine\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}}{\cellcolor{Gray}S} &\multicolumn{1}{m{6cm}}{}\\ SGBDR & Système de Gestion de Bases de Données Relationnelles\\
SQL & Structured Query Language\\
SSH & Secure Shell\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}}{\cellcolor{Gray}T} &\multicolumn{1}{m{6cm}}{} \\
TMA & Tierce Maintenance Applicative\\
TPT & Teradata Parallel Transporter\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}}{\cellcolor{Gray}U} &\multicolumn{1}{m{6cm}}{} \\ UO & Unités Organisationnelles\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}}{\cellcolor{Gray}W} &\multicolumn{1}{m{6cm}}{} \\WEBI & WEB Intelligence\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your tables are to wide to bi fit in the used text width. you have two possibilities: (i) increase text width, or (ii) reduce table width. also your tables contain lot of clutter ...

Comment: can you help me organize it !!!!

Comment: Help me to resolve it !!

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
\documentclass{report}
%\usepackage{geometry}                                     % for determine page layout
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array, multirow, makecell,
            tabularx}                                       % added
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash }m{#1}}   % not used
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash }b{#1}}  % not used
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }b{#1}}    % not used
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}                           % changed from 1.2
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}
                    *{2}{p{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}
                             @{}}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{c >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\cellcolor{Gray} A  &                                       \\
AIX                 & Advanced Interactive eXecutive        \\
AMP                 & Access Module Processor               \\  \hline
\cellcolor{Gray} B  &                                       \\
BDDF                & Banque De Détail en France            \\
BI                  & Business Intelligence                 \\
BNPP                & Banque Nationale de Paris Paribas     \\
BO                  & Business Objects                      \\
BPF                 & Banque Privée France                  \\
BTEQ                & Batch \textbf{TE}radata Query         \\ \hline
\cellcolor{Gray} C  &                                       \\
CBP                 & Centre de Banque Privée               \\
CEO                 & Chief Executive Officer               \\ \hline
\cellcolor{Gray} D  &                                       \\
DR                  & Direction Régionale                   \\
DTU                 & Dossier de Test Unitaires             \\  \hline
\cellcolor{Gray} E  &                                       \\
ENSA                & Ecole Nationale des Sciences Appliquées   \\
ETL                 & Extract Transform Load                \\  \hline
\cellcolor{Gray} F  &                                       \\
FDC                 & Fond De Commerce externe              \\  \hline
\cellcolor{Gray} G  &                                       \\
GL                  & Génie Logiciel                        \\  \hline
\cellcolor{Gray} I  &                                       \\
IAC                 & Info centre Animation Commercial      \\
IBM                 & International Business Machines       \\
IBM AT              & IBM Applications \& Technologies      \\
\end{tabularx}
    &
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{c >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
                    &                                       \\
IHM                 & Interface Hommes Machines\\
IPS                 & IT Production Services\\
IT                  &  Information Technology               \\  \hline
\cellcolor{Gray} K  &                                       \\
KM & Knowledge Management\\
KSH & Korn shell\\\hline
\cellcolor{Gray}M   &                                       \\
MEP                 & la Mise En Pr oduction\\
MEQ                 & la Mise En Qualification\\
MOA                 & Maitrise d’OuvrAge\\
MOE                 & Maitrise d’Oeuvre \\
MPP                 & Massively Parallel Processing\\\hline
\cellcolor{Gray} O  &                                       \\
ODBC                & Open DataBase Connectivity\\\hline
\cellcolor{Gray} P  &                                       \\
PE                  & Parsing Engine\\\hline
\cellcolor{Gray} S  &                                       \\
SGBDR               & Système de Gestion de Bases de Données Relationnelles\\
SQL                 & Structured Query Language\\
SSH                 & Secure Shell\\\hline
\cellcolor{Gray} T  &                                       \\
TMA                 & Tierce Maintenance Applicative\\
TPT                 & Teradata Parallel Transporter\\\hline
\cellcolor{Gray} U  &                                       \\
UO                  & Unités Organisationnelles\\\hline
\cellcolor{Gray} W  &                                       \\
WEBI                & WEB Intelligence                      \\  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\end{document}


\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
%\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array, multirow, makecell,
            tabularx}                                       % added
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash }m{#1}}   % not used
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash }b{#1}}  % not used
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }b{#1}}    % not used
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}                           % changed from 1.2
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}
                    *{2}{p{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}
                             @{}}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{c >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\cellcolor{Gray} A  &                                       \\
AIX                 & Advanced Interactive eXecutive        \\
AMP                 & Access Module Processor               \\  \hline
\cellcolor{Gray} B  &                                       \\
BDDF                & Banque De Détail en France            \\
BI                  & Business Intelligence                 \\
BNPP                & Banque Nationale de Paris Paribas     \\
BO                  & Business Objects                      \\
BPF                 & Banque Privée France                  \\
BTEQ                & Batch \textbf{TE}radata Query         \\ \hline
\cellcolor{Gray} C  &                                       \\
CBP                 & Centre de Banque Privée               \\
CEO                 & Chief Executive Officer               \\ \hline
\cellcolor{Gray} D  &                                       \\
DR                  & Direction Régionale                   \\
DTU                 & Dossier de Test Unitaires             \\  \hline
\cellcolor{Gray} E  &                                       \\
ENSA                & Ecole Nationale des Sciences Appliquées   \\
ETL                 & Extract Transform Load                \\  \hline
\cellcolor{Gray} F  &                                       \\
FDC                 & Fond De Commerce externe              \\  \hline
\cellcolor{Gray} G  &                                       \\
GL                  & Génie Logiciel                        \\  \hline
\cellcolor{Gray} I  &                                       \\
IAC                 & Info centre Animation Commercial      \\
IBM                 & International Business Machines       \\
IBM AT              & IBM Applications \& Technologies      \\
\end{tabularx}
    &
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{c >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
                    &                                       \\
IHM                 & Interface Hommes Machines\\
IPS                 & IT Production Services\\
IT                  &  Information Technology               \\  \hline
\cellcolor{Gray} K  &                                       \\
KM & Knowledge Management\\
KSH & Korn shell\\\hline
\cellcolor{Gray}M   &                                       \\
MEP                 & la Mise En Pr oduction\\
MEQ                 & la Mise En Qualification\\
MOA                 & Maitrise d’OuvrAge\\
MOE                 & Maitrise d’Oeuvre \\
MPP                 & Massively Parallel Processing\\\hline
\cellcolor{Gray} O  &                                       \\
ODBC                & Open DataBase Connectivity\\\hline
\cellcolor{Gray} P  &                                       \\
PE                  & Parsing Engine\\\hline
\cellcolor{Gray} S  &                                       \\
SGBDR               & Système de Gestion de Bases de Données Relationnelles\\
SQL                 & Structured Query Language\\
SSH                 & Secure Shell\\\hline
\cellcolor{Gray} T  &                                       \\
TMA                 & Tierce Maintenance Applicative\\
TPT                 & Teradata Parallel Transporter\\\hline
\cellcolor{Gray} U  &                                       \\
UO                  & Unités Organisationnelles\\\hline
\cellcolor{Gray} W  &                                       \\
WEBI                & WEB Intelligence                      \\  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

even beter result you will obtain if you will uncomment row with `\usepackage{geometry}`. in this case the table will look as follows:

[image]